# Quais as diferenças entre a BCL e a FCL?

Tags: c#, .net, framework

A Base Class Library (BCL) Framework Class Library (FCL) são componentes do .NET. O que define o que cada uma faz?

O que entra em cada uma?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A BCL é a biblioteca base mesmo, como o próprio nome diz. Ela contém tudo o que é fundamental para trabalhar com o .NET, incluindo aí toda infraestrutura que a linguagem C#, e as que sejam muito parecidas, vão usar diretamente.

Ela faz parte da especificação da CLI (Common Language Infrastructure) e pode ser usada por qualquer linguagem que seja construída em cima do .NET ou outra implementação da CLI.

Qualquer outra implementação da CLI deve obrigatoriamente ter toda BCL. Exemplos do que tem nela são todos os tipos básicos da linguagem, IO, coleções, atributos, exceções básicas, delegados, etc.

A FCL é o que vem adicionalmente e não precisa existir obrigatoriamente em uma implementação CLI. É o que ajuda em tarefas mais específicas que não são tão básicas assim. Podemos considerar assim a manipulação de XML, WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET, ADO.NET etc. A BCL é um dos componentes da FCL.

Note que o Mono ou o .NET Core não possuem vários destes componentes e mesmo assim são CLI *compliant*.

No diagrama da infraestrutura completa pode ser visto a diferença:

[image: BCL X FCL]

Isso se tornou menos importante com o declínio do .NET Framework. O .NET Core tem uma organização um pouco diferente e os componentes que são classificados como FCL são mais independentes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).