# Posso criar um aplicativo Win32 em C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

Tenho consciência que C# é o braço direito do .NET Framework, e que a linguagem padrão para programar aplicativos Win32 é C++. Mas, eu consigo programar um aplicativo em C#, independente de qualquer biblioteca do .NET Framework?

Em outros termos, posso criar um aplicativo inteiramente escrito em C#, que não usa **nenhuma biblioteca do .NET Framework**, para que possa ser executado **utilizando apenas o *runtime* do Windows, e não do .NET Framework?**

Comment: Só para confirmar: queres criar um executavel, certo? Então a resposta é sim. Basta abrires o visual studio , criar um novo projecto , escolher o template windows e depois windows forms applications. A partir é programar a partir daí.

Comment: Não exatamente, **quero criar um aplicativo que não dependa do .NET Framework para ser executado.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ser independente do .NET Framework é diferente de ser independente de qualquer coisa.

É possível criar um executável nativo usando C# ou outra linguagem padrão .NET com [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101). Ele é um conjunto de ferramentas que permite converter o [CIL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138577/101) para binário nativo da plataforma. Claro que possui uma biblioteca que age como o *runtime* da linguagem que é necessário. Por exigência do C# esse *runtime* não consegue ser tão pequeno assim, mas é bem menor que o .NET Framework e pode ficar todo contido dentro do próprio executável nativo *tem uns trambiques que podem ser feitos, [dá para fazer ficar com 4KB](https://github.com/MichalStrehovsky/zerosharp), mas subverte o que é realmente o C#).

Essa exigência de não ter mais nada só pode ser atendida por Assembly e mais ou menos C, mesmo assim fazendo algo bem básico. [Entenda como o .NET funciona](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101). Dá para reduzir parte de infraestrutura toda, mas não dá para eliminar tudo sem impossibilitar a linguagem de ser o que é, de dar a segurança normalmente oferecida.

Tão pouco dá para funcionar sem várias das classes da BCL. A linguagem se suporta em cima de muitas delas e mesmo as que não são dependência direta da linguagem ainda são usadas na maioria das aplicações. É claro que um executável autocontido não precisa ter mais que o código usado, não precisa carregar toda [BCL ou FCL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194677/101). Igual em toda linguagem. Mesmo C depende de uma biblioteca. Eu só não sei dizer se é inteligente o suficiente para separar o que usa em cada classe ou precisa colocar ela toda, ou ainda toda unidade de compilação se for um [*linker*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/191565/101). Tem caso que nem pode correr o risco de eliminar certas coisas.

Claro que algumas funcionalidades podem ser comprometidas sem a plataforma completa. Reflexão mesmo é um pouco limitada, mas em executável nativo ela tem pouca serventia mesmo.

Também tem o [LLILC](https://github.com/dotnet/llilc) usando [LLVM](https://llvm.org/).

Tem outras formas de usar o meio termo onde não precisa do .NET Framework instalado na máquina, mas também não chega ser um executável nativo. Pode ser o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101), o [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/), alguns modelos do [Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). [No iOS o Xamarin gera código nativo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/architecture?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Todos eles são independentes do .NET Framework ou outra plataforma que precisa estar previamente instalada.

O .NET Framework é só uma das formas de servir C#, e [está entrando em desuso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101), inclusive o .NET Native não tem muito futuro, uma pena.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/CallFunction.cs).

Comment: Mas eu posso criar um aplicativo independente do .NET Framework inteiramente feito em C#? Isso é possível? Em outras palavras, compilar um executável Win32 (sem ser .NET Framework) diretamente de um código C#?

Comment: Pode sim com o .NET Native.Claro que sempre terá um *runtime* o que praticamente toda linguagem tem, o C# exige um meio grandinho, mas não exige um componente a parte. O .NET Core está no meio do caminho. Tem um componente que faz tudo funcionar sem precisar nada instalado, mas não é um executável nativo. O Mono sempre foi assim. O Xamarin tem mais de um modelo.Acho que agora entendi o que perguntou, como usou o termo incorreto achei que queria outra coisa.

Comment: Também acho, mas sua resposta complementa sobre a iteração de .NET com Win32 e acho isso bem útil, vou atualizar minha pergunta para que possa entender melhor.

Comment: A resposta original que não era o que o PA queria está em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227656/101.