# O que é e para que server o Target Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio

Trabalho a algum tempo com *.NET* e fui questionado sobre o *target framework* dos meus projetos.

[image: Target framework]

Entendo pra que serve mas não soube explicar de forma **simples** e **clara** o que exatamente é.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Exemplos:

*.NET Framework 2.0:* Você terá os recursos presentes na versão 2.0 do .NET e nos computadores "clientes", será necessário ter o .NET 2.0 instalado.

*.NET Framework 4.6.1:* Você terá os recursos presentes na versão 4.6.1 do .NET e nos computadores "clientes", será necessário ter o .NET 4.6.1 instalado.

Se for trabalhar com LINQ por exemplo, esse recurso só está disponível a partir da versão 3.5 do .NET, nas versões anteriores, não será possível desenvolver utilizando LINQ. Há outros vários recursos que são inseridos ou descontinuados a cada atualização, normalmente mantendo a retrocompatibilidade. Acredito que o ideal seja sempre preferir os mais atuais, salvo se tiver algum requisito específico.

Situações que acontecem ao publicar uma aplicação:

*1-*
**Desenvolver com .NET 2.0** e rodar em uma máquina Windows XP SP2 < Windows 8: Aplicação Roda de forma nativa, uma vez que esses S.O. já possuem o framework instalado.

Em máquinas Windows 8 ou superior, será necessário a instalação do pacote .Net 2.0 e 3.5 pelo painel de controle > adicionar ou remover recursos do windows.

*2-*
**Desenvolver com .NET 4**, para rodar em versões mais antigas do windows, será necessária a instalação do pacote pelo instalador publicado pela microsoft, verificando a compatibilidade com o S.O. Nas versões mais atuais (8 à 10) a aplicação irá rodar de forma nativa.

Comment: massa, acho que já consigo explicar o que é :P valeu

Answer (score 12):

Existem diversas versões de *frameworks* como pode ser visto na tela. Na verdade existem bem mais que estes, já que não existe só o .NET Framework, existe, o .NET Core, o .NET Native, o Xamarin, o Mono, o .NET Micro Framework, entre outros. Claro que você só pode usar o que está instalado na sua máquina. Claro que no caso do .NET Framework isto é mais importante porque ele funciona como uma plataforma própria completa e precisa ter instalado na máquina do usuário.

No momento que for gerar os binários da sua aplicação é importante indicar qual versão pretende usar para ele configurar tudo corretamente e analisar se pode suar tudo o que deseja. Então se indicar que usará uma versão mais antiga, não terá acesso aos recursos das versões mais novas. Se indicar que vai usar uma versão mais nova sua aplicação só rodará em máquinas que possuem aquela versão do .NET, mesmo que você não tenha usado nada específico dela. Evidente que o instalador apropriado fará o *upgrade* do .NET pra você se for necessário.

Se não me engano só a versão 3.5 ainda é suportada oficialmente, as anteriores existem por compatibilidade. Particularmente sempre prefiro a versão mais atual que é a 4.7.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: boa explicação, obrigado.

Comment: É possível desenvolver sem .net framework ? Acho que é impossivel

Comment: @MatheusMiranda sim, é possível https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227301/101. Estou em uma máquina provisória e sem VS para copiar tela com outros *targets*.

Answer (score 7):

> When you target a framework in an app or library, you're specifying the set of APIs that you'd like to make available to the app or library. You specify the target framework in your project file using Target Framework Monikers (TFMs).

Pelo que eu entendi [nesse link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) caso você entenda um pouco de inglês, é que o target framework "aponta" qual versão seu app ou biblioteca estará disponível(compatibilidade). Isso inclui recursos de linguagem de programação e *padrões de desenvolvimento*