# O que é um pacote Nuget "multi-target"?

Tags: .net, packages, nuget

A minha dúvida é sobre gerar um package do Nuget "multi-target", o que seria isso?

Eu sei que o package é compilado em uma versão *target*, .Net Framework 4.5, Core 2.0, etc.

Até pesquisei aqui, e encontrei essa pergunta relacionada, mas ela fala exatamente do comentei na linha anterior: [O que é e para que server o Target Framework?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227396/57220)

O que gostaria de saber é o que é o multi-target?

Suporta mais de uma versão do .Net Framework num mesmo package?

Como gerar um package assim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em geral, quando se cria um package nuget pretende-se que ele seja o mais inclusivo e menos restritivo quanto possível, podendo ser utilizado nos mais diversos projetos, independentemente da versão do framework que é usado por quem importe o seu pacote. Apesar de já existirem há um bom tempo, o uso de packages multi-target tornou-se especialmente popular com a introdução do .net core, uma vez que o netstandard e o .net core ainda não tinham todas as funcionalidades presentes no "full framework".

Imagine um cenário onde um pacote para .net 4.5 também precise ser usado em projetos .net core 2.* ou 3.*. Uma forma prática de permitir o uso de pacotes em ambas as vertentes do .net é utilizar o `netstandard`, em especial o `netstandard 2.0`, pela sua ampla compatibilidade (devido ao aumento significativo da sua api). Entretanto, o `netstandard 2.0` somente é compatível com versões acima do .net 4.6.1. Neste caso, seria necessário criar um pacote multi-target. Obs: Para confirmar a compatibilidade do netstandard, pode-se usar [esta página](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/dotnet-standard).

Como criar um pacote multi-target vai depender de como o seu pacote é criado, mas via de norma, basta criar um diretório para cada target dentro de `lib/`. A lista completa de "targets" pode ser encontrada [nesta página](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks#supported-frameworks).

Outra forma de se criar este tipo de pacote é especificando dependências distintas para cada target no seu arquivo .nupkg.

```xml
<dependencies>
  <group targetFramework="net45">
    (...)
  </group>

  <group targetFramework="netstandard2.0">
    (...)
  </group>
</dependencies>
```

Caso não esteja manipulando diretamente a construção do pacote, uma forma de se criar um pacote multi-target é criando um projeto "Class Library" e alterando o `TargetFramework` por `TargetFrameworks` no csproj. ex:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net45</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Deste modo, ao executar o comando `dotnet pack` será criado um pacote multi-target configurado corretamente.