# Como o C# é executado em outras plataformas?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cross-platform, clr

Como complemento a esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/227301/posso-criar-um-aplicativo-win32-em-c), rodar C# num sistema onde o .NET Framework é nativo, é padrão executar o executável do aplicativo. Até onde sei, o **C#** depende do .NET Framework para ser **compilado e executado**, e assim ter todas funções do código rodando nativamente na sua plataforma.

Mas e quanto ao Linux? Eu sei que sem o .NET Core instalado ele não irá conseguir executar um aplicativo *nativamente do .NET*, mas isso exige a sua instalação na máquina.

Quando vou rodar um aplicativo que foi escrito em C# em um celular, eu não instalo nenhuma dependência, o aplicativo roda de forma nativa e estável, e sem o .NET Framework. **Como que isso acontece?**

Existe uma sub-plataforma .NET Framework em todos dispositivos compatíveis com .NET Core? Ou o .NET Core se adapta nas plataformas? Se sim, como ele faz isso? Há alguma perda de performance significativa?

Comment: não tenho informação suficiente pra elaborar uma resposta, mas mobile, o código já é compilado pra plataforma destino, não vai ser um programa .net...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis por que não é assim em todas plataformas?

Comment: O @RovannLinhalis está meio certo. Por exemplo: O Xamarin.Android empacota código IL (código da plataforma .NET) junto com o JITter da plataforma específica e suas dependências. Dessa forma o código que está no device é código .NET.

Comment: Eu não sei se entendi bem o propósito da pergunta. Mas, basicamente, é o mesma coisa que qqr aplicação normal, é gerado "código de máquina". No caso do Android, é gerado código IL que vai empacotado com a VM (do Mono, eu acho) e um JITer. No caso do iOS é gerado código de máquina a partir do código IL (era assim anteriormente, não posso afirmar que ainda seja). Só não sei como funciona a questão do gerenciamento de memória no iOS, já que não tem como ter um garbage collector. Imagino que a conversão IL -> código de máquina tenha algo pra gerenciar memória. Precisaria dar uma lida p/ entender.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Mas e quanto ao Linux? Eu sei que sem o .NET Core instalado ele não irá conseguir executar um aplicativo nativamente do .NET, mas isso exige a sua instalação na máquina.

Isso não é verdade. O .NET Core não é igual ao .NET Framework justamente por isso. Ele não precisa estar instalado. Na verdade nem pode ser instalado. Ele é um SDK que você usa no seu ambiente de desenvolvimento e uma biblioteca que vai junto com sua aplicação. É possível usar parte do SDK para compartilhar o ambiente se quiser.

> Quando vou rodar um aplicativo que foi escrito em C# em um celular, eu não instalo nenhuma dependência, o aplicativo roda de forma nativa e estável, e sem o .NET Framework. Como que isso acontece?

Esse é um outro caso. Ele usa o Mono (partindo do .NET 5 o Mono não será usado mais, o que era chamado de .NET Core poderá resolver isso nesta versão) que tem a capacidade de gerar código nativo diretamente, sem precisar de um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101), até por exigência da própria plataforma (iOS). Ele gera o executável assim como o C ou C++ gera.

Na verdade, existe o .NET Native que também faz isso, mas está disponível apenas para alguns tipos de aplicação. Também não será mais usado.

Eles usam um compilador normal que gera um código nativo. Isso é o normal, o estranho é o que o .NET Framework faz.

> Existe uma sub-plataforma .NET Framework em todos os dispositivos compatíveis com .NET Core? Ou o .NET Core se adapta nas plataformas? Se sim, como ele faz isso? Há alguma perda de performance significativa?

Não, isso não faz o menor sentido. O .NET Framework faz parte do sistema operacional Windows, por isso ele tende a ser pouco usado, já que hoje há demanda por algo mais padrão.

O .NET Core tem performance bastante superior em vários pontos, o .NET Native mais ainda (na verdade isso foi se invertendo). O Mono, e, portanto, o Xamarin, tem performance pior em alguns pontos, mas está melhorando, mas quando usado com código nativo pode ser mais rápido que o .NET Framework.

O .NET Framework tenderá ser usado como legado a partir do ano que vem quando o que falta para o Windows estará disponível para ele. Ainda mais que [ele morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Eu adoraria que tudo fosse nativo, mas ele possui limitações técnicas que algumas aplicações não podem aceitar. Há menos controle e menos capacidade principalmente de reflexão, o que impede uma série de bibliotecas de funcionar. Em alguns casos pode exigir a duplicação do conteúdo, o que não é desejável.

O gráfico da outra resposta está obsoleto (na verdade a resposta não responde ao que foi perguntado e fala do .NET Standard que não foi perguntado), e agora na última edição minha aqui ela está mais obsoleta ainda.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade não, só o AP.

Comment: Mas a idéia de usar uma linguagem intermediária que seria executada por uma máquina virtual (CLR no caso do .NET, equivalente ao JVM para o Java) não era a proposta para que o mesma aplicação rodasse em múltiplas plataformas. Bastaria criar uma VM para a plataforma e a aplicação seria executada sem problemas. Não era essa a promessa, pelo menos em 2002, quando o .NET foi lançado?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro tenha em mente a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O .NET FRAMERWORK, .NET CORE e o XAMARIN, todas elas são conformes com o .NET STANDARD.

O .NET STANDARD é uma especificação e não um framework.
"O .NET Standard é uma interface, uma espécie de contrato que define a lista de APIs que aquela determinada versão do .NET deve suportar."

Se você inspecionar o repositório no github vai ver um conjunto de métodos vazios e/ou funções que retornam nulo. Veja o [System.Console.WriteLine](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/4917e8d6c02b4dbc6d9fb0be8d5b3b0fc7e4bff7/netstandard/ref/System.cs), por exemplo:

```
public static void WriteLine(string value) { }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qualquer devenvolvedor poderá criar sua própria framework para uma plataforma específica (exemplo .NET CORE para Z80 MSX), desde que respeite o .NET Standard.

Hoje você tem o XAMARIN (iOS, OS X e Android), .NET CORE (Windows, Linux e macOS) e .NET FRAMEWORK (Windows). Note que algumas assemblies do .NET Framework não fazem parte da Standard, exemplo System.Windows.Forms, e provavelmente nunca farão parte.

Ou seja, é permitido um Framework conforme ao .NET Standard adicionar Assemblies que não fazem parte do .NET Standard, mas não é permitido modificar ou remover os Assemblies que já estão lá.

Para saber mais eu sugiro o artigo do MVP Eduardo Pires: [.NET Standard – Você precisa conhecer!](http://www.eduardopires.net.br/2017/06/net-standard-voce-precisa-conhecer/)

Comment: "_Ele é um conjunto de de métodos vazios e funções que retornam nulo_" Isso não tá de acordo. O NET Standard contém o contrato (assim como usamos interfaces nos nossos códigos) que precisa ser seguido por quem o implementa.

Comment: @Linq concordo. Eu quis simplificar o máximo possível e ficou ruim. Vou reformular.

Answer (score 0):

O .Net deriva das idéias do JAVA.

A Sun que enfrentava dificuldades ao ter que lidar com muitas plataformas desenvolveu o conceito: "Write once run everywhere": "escreva uma vez e rode em qualquer lugar".

Como seria possível rodar o mesmo código num chip embarcado e num x64? A solução na época (e o java até hoje é assim), foi abstrair a linguagem de programação, o desenvolvedor escreve o programa numa linguagem genérica, esse código é compilado em um bytecode intermediário, e distribui-se esse bytecode.

Ao executar um programa JAVA, a máquina java (jre, java runtime environment, que é específico da plataforma) converte o bytecode para código nativo, carrega na memória, seta o ponteiro de execução e pronto, você tem o seu código nativo executando em múltiplas plataformas.

No final você acaba tendo:

1 compilador de JAVA.

1 bytecode intermediário

n ambientes de runtime (um para cada plataforma)

Ao invés de ter n compiladores para cada plataforma.

Realmente não vejo grande vantagem nisso, do ponto de vista de engenharia, se comparado a ter n compiladores. Na verdade há um revés: os programas demoram mais a iniciar.

A Microsoft seguiu esse modelo, porém adaptou o conteito para várias linguagens:

n compiladores (um para cada linguagem).

1 linguagem intermediária

m ambientes de runtime (um para cada plataforma)

A vantagem disso é ter: n+m programas, caso tivesse um compilador para cada par (linguagem, plataforma) resultaria em n*m programas.

O que se instala no Linux para rodar aplicativos .Net Core é o ambiente de runtime, mas é possível gerar um programa compilado com o runtime embutido (que te gera um programa bem grande).

O ambiente de runtime chama as funções nativas quando necessário e lida com ponteiros e handlers do sistema operacional.

Há grande ansiedade por parte dos desenvolvedores em se gerar código nativo a partir do .Net, e esse é um dos fatores de decisão ao se escolher uma linguagem/compilador.