# O Node no mundo .NET seria o CLR ou o .NET?

Tags: .net, node.js, clr

Tendo em vista que o Node é uma plataforma de desenvolvimento *server-side* em JS... e no .NET nós temos o CLR (Common Language Runtime) o Node seria o CLR que compila? Ou um *framework* como .NET, como dois importam módulos eu fiquei bem confuso quanto a essa questão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pergunta está formulada de uma forma que não reflete a realidade.

De certa forma podemos comparar a plataforma .NET com o Node.js. A plataforma envolve uma série de coisas.

O [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) é o *runtime*, algo que o Node tem também, então acho que CLR está para o V8 do Node.

Na verdade, a plataforma .NET é um padrão e existem várias implementações. Até onde sei o Node só tem uma, mesmo o [Deno](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/444449/101) não é compatível.

De fato o compilador do .NET não faz parte do CLR. Nas implementações mais comuns do .NET o mais comum é usar o [.NET Compiler Platform](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82756/101). O Node pega o fonte e JITta diretamente. O CLR tem um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) também, mas parte de um código previamente compilado.

Outro componente importante da plataforma é a [FCL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194677/101).

Outros componentes podem ser opcionais, como ocorre no Node também.

A questão dos módulos não está clara, acho que cabe uma pergunta específica com mais detalhes da dúvida. Mas acho que há semelhanças, o .NET obtém com Nuget e o Node com NPM.

Comment: Essa foi a minha duvida... eu fiquei tão confuso que nem sabia como expressar ela...