# Qual tipo é herdado duma array em .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, array

Se declaramos uma `List`, temos certeza que seu tipo é explicitamente o `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

Mas e quando declaramos um *array*? Qual é o tipo genérico implementado por trás da mesma?

Exemplo:

```
string[] objeto = {"Olá,", " mundo!"};
```

Ao obtermos o `Type.FullName` de `objeto`, temos um `"System.String[]"` como saída, mas nenhum tipo que implementa ou herda a classe. Isso não nos esclarece nada a respeito.

Assim como uma `List<>`, *arrays* também tem funções e métodos nativos.

A pergunta é: de que classe vêm estes métodos? Basicamente, preciso saber se um tipo `T[]` há alguma classe, estrutura ou interface implementável e mutável por tipo, de forma que seja possível realizar uma declaração explícita, por exemplo:

```
public void foo(string[] array) { ... }
...
System.Collections.Generic.TipoAnonimo<string> bar = {"foo", "bar"};
foo(bar);  // OK
```

> **Observação:** não pretendo usar LINQ nestas operações.

Comment: Chegou analisar a documentação? se não, da uma olhadinha nela veja se te ajuda... https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Lodi eu li, mas não achei nada dizendo que `Byte[]` podia ser convertido para um Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação da Microsoft é boa em relação a este tipo de dúvida. Recomendo que você sempre consulte lá.

Conforme podemos ver na documentação da classe `System.Array` disponível [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.array?view=netcore-2.2), esta classe implementa algumas interfaces:

```cs
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, System.Collections.IList, System.Collections.IStructuralComparable, System.Collections.IStructuralEquatable
```

O tipo que você vai declarar pode ser qualquer uma das interfaces mencionadas acima ou até mesmo as interfaces que são base delas, como por exemplo: `IEnumerable` ou `ICollection`. Depende do que você quer fazer com o objeto em questão.

Answer (score 3):

A classe `Array` descrita na outra resposta é essencialmente utilitária e não é o tipo `array` da linguagem, e por isso neste raro caso específico consultar a documentação da biblioteca não é a forma correta de avaliar. Este tipo é especial na linguagem, assim como um `int` que mesmo traduzido para `Int32` se você for olhar a estrutura lá não verá nada de como funciona um inteiro, só métodos utilitários. Isto está na [especificação (19.1.1)](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-334%201st%20edition%20December%202001.pdf):

> System.Array is not itself an array-type

Implicitamente por força de especificação (10.4.6) e implementado no compilador o tipo `array` herda conceitualmente do tipo `Array` que herda de `Object` como todos os tipos em C# e as interfaces descritas na outra resposta, então a resposta até acerta por tabela, mas pelos motivos errados e com explicação errada.

Então não podemos tratar *array* de forma como tratamos outras estruturas de dados, ela recebe tratamento especial do compilador. Inclusive algumas pessoas dizem que o *array* que a gente conhece deveria ser mais simples e não fazer parte do tipo do C# e ser usado apenas para alocar memória de de forma especial e ser usado internamente em outras estruturas de dados, inclusive o tipo `Array` que seria do jeito que está acostumado em outros lugares, assim como o `List` que internamente é um *array*.

O AP teve uma intuição que algo estava errado ali e chegou comentar sobre isto, mas acabou apagando.

Eu não entendi bem a parte final da dúvida por isso não a respondi, mas parece interessante.

Comment: Boa resposta, Maniero, mas há algo que ainda me intriga: por ser um tipo especial, `Object[]` é uma característica da linguagem ou do .NET Framework em si? Percebi que ao tentar extrair o nome da classe de uma instância deste tipo, é retornado algo como `Array'Object[]` e não como `Array<Object>`. Especifiquei sobre o Linq para não esperar nenhuma resposta do tipo "use o `.ToArray()`".

Comment: Ambos. É da biblioteca, ao contrário do `array`, mas tem uma série de coisas que o compilador trata desse tipo de forma especial. Mas ele é um tipo *full*, do jeito que você vê na biblioteca é assim que funciona pra tudo. Em geral as diferenças é pra otimizações os situações específicas por ele ser o tipo geral. Alias vamos começar falar do .NET ou até da BCL porque o .NET Framework morreu. Retorna desta forma porque é um tipo especial. Se a classe que o Pedro citou fosse o tipo então a reflexão mostraria como você está "esperando".

Comment: o que é BCL? Por que o .NET Framework morreu?

Comment: achei a resposta para o que é BCL [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/194677/quais-as-diferen%c3%a7as-entre-a-bcl-e-a-fcl), mas não entendi ainda o fato do ".NET Framework estar morto".

Comment: Se falta uma pergunta no SOpt o que você deve fazer? :)

Comment: [Perguntei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/385594/o-net-framework-est%c3%a1-morto).